# Need a kid-safe browser like Zoodles

Tags: 12.10, browser

I have a six year old little sister. She gets online. My parents want her on a kid safe browser like Zoodles.

Are there any for Linux? Is it possible to install Zoodles on Linux? All the ones I've found download the install stuff for windows.

Also. I'm brand new to Linux, so instructions on how to would be much appreciated. =3

I have Ubuntu 12.10, Just in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has the [Blocksi Web Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blocksi-web-filtering-and/pgmjaihnmedpcdkjcgigocogcbffgkbn) extension.

Is it something like this you are looking for?

Comment: I'm sure it'd work. I was just wanting a program like zoodles, where it has all the games and videos and crap for easy access. She's not exactly very smart.
I'll try that chrome add-on though. Thank you. =3

Answer (score 0):

I have found something really interesting for you. That's actually not a browser , Its a add-on but it do more than you need and it will keep children safe in Internet.All you need to have is simply firefox web-browser.

That add-on named as  [kidzui](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/kidzui/). This is really great.

some feature of KidZui add-on.

> - KidZui is a Firefox add-on that with one click turns Firefox into a
>     kid-safe environment with over a million kid-friendly websites, games,
>     pictures, and YouTube videos.
> - Parents and teachers review content for KidZui so your kids can surf
>     independently.
> - The KidZui browser uses a Zooming User Interface paradigm to make
>     browsing easier for children.
> - Search results appear as scaled down images of websites, videos, and
>     pictures that children click on to zoom in and see content.
> - Children build avatars called Zuis to represent themselves online.
>     Children can share KidZui content with friends online. To add a friend
>     online, children need to know the friends Zui name. There is no online
>     directory of Zui names, so children need to get their friends Zui
>     names offline in order to add them.
> - Friends also need to be approved by parents before they become
>     available in the browser. KidZui also tracks children’s Internet usage
>     and sends reports to their parents on what their children looked at
>     online.

Comment: not compatible with Firefox 26.0

Comment: Link is broken :(